# How to play blu rays on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: blu-ray

this question has been asked many different times and ways for many different ubuntu versions, but because technology is constantly evolving, i feel it is important to ask this question as it pertains to ubuntu 20.04

I recently reformatted my computer from ubuntu 20.04 to ubuntu 20.04, and on my previous version i was able to use by blu ray drive to burn and watch blu ray movies.

So when i reformatted my computer i am no longer able to play or burn blu ray drives, and i don't know why, i don't know why because i don't know what ever i did last time.

i went to this article, https://www.howtogeek.com/240487/how-to-play-dvds-and-blu-rays-on-linux/

and it tells me to enter a command into the terminal

cd ~/.config/aacs/ && wget http://vlc-bluray.whoknowsmy.name/files/KEYDB.cfg

but when i run this command i get an error

ERROR: cannot verify vlc-bluray.whoknowsmy.name's certificate, issued by ‘CN=R3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US’: Issued certificate has expired.

and i'm wondering if this is what i need to do, and i wanted to post this question and see if anyone knew what to do, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me on Triskel 10 (Ubuntu 20.04 compatible):

1. Install required packages:

   `sudo apt install vlc libaacs0 libbluray-bdj libbluray2`
2. Download Blu-Ray decryption keys:
   Form here:

   http://fvonline-db.bplaced.net

If you are unsure download this:

```
http://fvonline-db.bplaced.net/fv_download.php?lang=eng
```

You must extract and copy it to:

```
$HOME/.config/aacs/KEYDB.cfg
```

**Warning: Destination path and file name must be exactly the same as above.**

**Note: This file is constantly updated on http://fvonline-db.bplaced.net. When you will get in to trouble with missing Blu-Ray decryption key you will have download new version of this file.**

3. Turn off Blu-Ray menu in VLC:

Disable Blu-Ray menu is required because VLC use broken libbluray which not work with Java 11 (required by libbluray from Ubuntu 20.04). Other reason maybe that new Blu-Ray movie discs using more recent Java versions. Short: When you use Java 8 VLC:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 /usr/bin/vlc bluray:///dev/sr0
```

shows menu, but it not works. When you use Java 11 (installed as required package by libbluray):

```
$ JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 /usr/bin/vlc bluray:///dev/sr0
VLC media player 3.0.9.2 Vetinari (revision 3.0.9.2-0-gd4c1aefe4d)
[000055b7013525b0] main libvlc: Uruchamianie vlc z domyślnym interfejsem. Użyj 'cvlc', aby używać vlc bez interfejsu.
[00007f16a4001120] libbluray demux: First play: 1, Top menu: 1
HDMV Titles: 2, BD-J Titles: 2, Other: 0
bdj.c:865: Detected Java 9 or later JVM - support is experimental !
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.Error: Properties init: Could not determine current working directory.
        at java.lang.System.initProperties(java.base/Native Method)
        at java.lang.System.initPhase1(java.base/System.java:1948)
```

VLC simply hangs.

**Note: You don't have Java in order to play Blu-Ray movies. Java is required only for fancy Blu-Ray disk menu.**

3.1. Run VLC and enter settings: Menu Tools->Preferences->Show All (in left bellow corner).
Then search 'blu'.
Then click Blu-ray and uncheck 'Menu'.
Then save and close VLC.

4. Play movie:

   /usr/bin/vlc bluray:///dev/sr0

Comment: I can confirm this works as expected. pay special attention to the `$HOME/.config/aacs/KEYDB.cfg` part. the keydb i pulled from the site unzipped all lower case. changing it to upper allowed me to watch in VLC after turning off the menu.

Comment: Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS.  It already had all but `libbluray-bdj` and its dependencies, which are easily resolved by `sudo apt install libbluray-bdj`.  Did that, downloaded the keys, extracted to that exact path and name, turned the menus off, and it worked!  Turned the menus back on, expecting a hang as mentioned in the answer, and it still worked!  So I guess it's a matter of preference now, whether to disable the menus and go directly to the feature, or to keep them.